# How to add HTML to Wix without using iframe?

Tags: html, velo

I'm trying to add custom HTML to my Wix site, but including Wix Javascript inside an iframe is restricted. Is there a way to achieve this functionality without using iframes?

I tried every other options related to add custom HTML or widgets. All lead to iframes.

Comment: Are you trying to add custom HTML, custom JS, or both? I don't believe there's an alternative to `iframe` for custom HTML, that's an intentional design decision on the part of the Wix developers.

Comment: custom html @nathanliang

Comment: Read the docs if you havent already ... https://www.wix.com/velo